# Error in the positioning of a point with L.GeoJson

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am having a problem and I cannot understand why.

This is the code :

```
const map = L.map('map');

const tileURL = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
L.tileLayer(tileURL).addTo(map);
map.setView([-34.603722, -58.381592], 8);

var points = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "idSitio": "46",
                "emplazamiento": "ARCF0628",
                "codigo": "CAGVR     ",
                "enplanmtto": "No",
                "nombresitio": "AGUAS ARG. - VARELA 1835",
                "categoria": "C",
                "area": "AMBA",
                "propiedad": "TERCEROS",
                "direccion": "Varela 1835 Capital Federal",
                "contrato": "TELEFONICA"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -34.6475166,
                    -58.4511706
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};

var layer = L.geoJson(points).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([-34.6475166,-58.4511706]).addTo(map);
```

Points are at the same Latitude and Longitude but on the map they are positioned in different places

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoJSON has coordinates in `[lng, lat]` order, but Leaflet in it's calls has coordinates in `[lat, lng]` order.

This means you have to swap coordinates in your set view and marker definition (presuming your GeoJSON is correct):

```
map.setView([-58.4511706, -34.6475166], 8);

var marker = L.marker([-58.4511706, -34.6475166]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you very much TomazicM, it was a simple thing but I couldn't find him =/.